# How to get the number of Firestore documents in flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a flutter app and using Cloud Firestore. I want to get the number of documents in the database.

I tried

```
Firestore.instance.collection('products').toString().length
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Keep a count in a meta document and set up cloud function for document onWrite that calls `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` upon your "count" field of your meta document.

Answer (score 10):

Firebase doesn't officially give any function to retrieve the number of documents in a collection, instead you can get all the documents of the collection and get the length of it..

There are two ways:

1)

```
final int documents = await Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots().length;
```

This returns a value of int. But, if you don't use await, it returns a Future.

2)

```
final QuerySnapshot qSnap = await Firestore.instance.collection('products').getDocuments();
final int documents = qSnap.documents.length;
```

This returns a value of int.

However, these both methods gets all the documents in the collection and counts it.

Thank you

Comment: I think that's not going to work... as it would return the future int... where as you would need this in streambuilder or future builder. 

Please share the complete snippet

Answer (score 10):

With Cloud Firebase 2.0, there is a new way to count documents in a collection. According to reference notes, the count does not count as a read per document but a metaData request:

"[AggregateQuery] represents the data at a particular location for retrieving metadata without retrieving the actual documents."

Example:

```
final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> productList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');

      Future<int> countProducts() async {
        AggregateQuerySnapshot query = await productList.count().get();
        debugPrint('The number of products: ${query.count}');
        return query.count;
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

It Should Be - `Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots().length.toString();`

Comment: Note that this will cause the client to download all of the documents in the collection just to get the count.  For large collections, this could be extremely inefficient and costly.

Comment: @DougStevenson, What is the best way to get the count?

Comment: @Olantobi The recommended solution is in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: @DougStevenson is the counter method is similar to incrementing count, whenever a child is added?

Comment: This returns a type of Future<int>, so how do you do anything at all with this?   It's not even valuable as a string, in the example you have provided, as it just shows errors, and the value of the string is "Instance of Future<int>"

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting all the documents using get() or snapshots() and counting them, we can use Firebase Aggregation Queries. This will provide you with the count.

Here is an example that works in Flutter :

```
final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products");
final query = collection.where("status", isEqualTo: "active");
final countQuery = query.count();
final AggregateQuerySnapshot snapshot = await countQuery.get();
debugPrint("Count: ${snapshot.count}");
```

You can find more details here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries

Answer (score 2):

Since you are waiting on a future, this must be place within an async function

```
QuerySnapshot productCollection = await 
Firestore.instance.collection('products').get();
int productCount = productCollection.size();
```

Amount of documents in the collection

Answer (score 2):

```
Future<int> getCount() async {
    int count = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('collection')
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.size);
    return count;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get all the documents from that collection, then you can get the length of all the documents by document List. The below could should get the job done.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('products').getDocuments.then((myDocuments){
 print("${myDocuments.documents.length}");
});
```

Comment: what if i have thousands of documents in each collection?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Future getCount({String id}) async => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(collection) //your collectionref
      .where('deleted', isEqualTo: false)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    var count = 0;
    count = value.docs.length;

    return count;
  });
```

this is in dart language...

Answer (score 0):

Above suggestions will cause the client to download all of the documents in the collection to get the count. As a workaround, if your write operations are not frequently happening, you can put the length of the documents to firebase remote config and change it whenever you add/delete documents from the Firestore collection. Then you can fetch the length from firebase remote configs when you need it.

Comment: how can u do this with remote config?

Comment: this solution can easily go out of sync (due to failed updates or malformed transaction isolation in the app side...), it is always a good practice to get a real data like a select count with a where clause or a Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots().length; (snapshots() is a stream and wont cause downloading all the documents in the database if you don't want to)

Answer (score 0):

Most Simplest Way :

```
int count = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Collection_Name').get().then((value) => value.size);
print(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to fetch data from firebase so the call will return a Future.
In order to get the int value you have to use the StreamBuilder widget or FutureBuilder.

For example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("<collection name>").getStream().snapshot(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(children: [
            Text(
                  "${snapshot.data!.docs.length}"
            )
          ]));
    });
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection("products")
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  print(querySnapshot.docs.length);
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score -1):

**@2022** Using the recent version of FirebaseFirestore  you can now get the count without retrieving the entire collection.

```
CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');

int count = (await ref.count().get()).count;
```